# Swift callback after object function

Tags: ios, swift, callback, swift3

I have a Class to store user geo info & get locations etc. This class object is used in the my Home ViewController.

Example:

```
class Geo {

    ...
    getLocation()
    getRoute()
    ...

}

class ViewController {
    var geo = Geo()
    geo.getRoute()

    // I want a call a function after getRoute is complete.
}
```

*One method which I know is using **delegate***, where my ViewController is delegate of the Geo class object. But is there any straight & simple method, cause any of methods of Geo object will be used by any controller in app.

Comment: Use completionHandler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been suggested in the comments you can pass a function to `getRoute` to be called when it is completed. You would have to change the declaration of `getRoute` to something like

```
func getRoute(_ completionHandler: (() -> Void)?) {...}
```

and then at the end of the `getRoute` implementation call:

```
if let completion = completionHandler {
    completion()
}
```

and when you call `getRoute` you simply have to pass the function you want to be called as the last argument:

```
geo.getRoute() {
   // do something when getRoute is finished
}
```

Comment: thanks, your answer worked for me! I have one more question, in another place, when I use same code it does not work, cause the main function is passing the control to location delegate. How to deal with this scenarios when control is passed to some other async function.

Comment: Can you maybe give an example of that code and be a little bit more specific about what doesn't work. (Possibly even ask a new SO question if the new question is different enough from this one, or just edit this question if they're almost the same)